# Stopping at a red light for a right turn in Massachusetts

Tags: usa, driving, massachusetts

The other day, I came across a situation where the driver in front of me had stopped on a red light, waiting to take a right turn. As far as I could see, there was no "No turn on red" sign posted anywhere, neither was there any incoming traffic from the left side, nor any pedestrian on the crosswalk.

Here's a snap of that exact intersection taken from Google Street View -

[image]

There is one red light straight ahead, which is for cars going straight onto the street. There is another red light towards the right, which is why (I assume) the driver had stopped.

My question is, if there is such a situation where there is a red light for the right turn, but there's no "No right turn on red" sign posted anywhere, what's the right way to proceed?

This is for the state of MA, by the way.

---

EDIT - The Google Street View [link](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.2947327,-71.3287568,3a,75y,174.19h,84.07t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s4H1Ki5b2R8s41Xd8naHXKw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1) for this intersection, if it helps.

Comment: That doesn't look like a right turn. That looks like a bend to the right. A right turn is at a junction where there is cross traffic rather than something like a T-junction that you have there

Comment: So, the right thing to do here would be to stop at the red?

Comment: I would say so, yes. Typically there would be a "no right turn on red" sign if not allowed, but from the picture, I don't think that is the kind of intersection that would allow right turn on red

Comment: Where is this intersection?

Comment: This is at the intersection of Oak St and Bacon St, in Natick, MA. Here's the Google Street View [link](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.2947327,-71.3287568,3a,75y,174.19h,84.07t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s4H1Ki5b2R8s41Xd8naHXKw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1) to this interesection. Maybe a closer view would help in this case. I couldn't post the entire screenshot because of size restrictions.

Comment: @Berwyn Given that the road does also continue straight ahead you could argue that there is also a right turn.  But I am not sure what defines a "turn" and I wouldn't want to argue the distinction with a policeman.

Comment: Ok. looking it on google maps, it does look more like an intersection that would allow right turn on red. I suspect the driver was just being cautious. Although you are allowed to turn right on red, you're not obliged to

Comment: Okay! This is like the worst possible situation to be in. Assuming I was the first car waiting to go right, and had stopped for the red, and the car behind me starts honking (quite frequent in this area), what should be the right thing? Stay put or go? I just recently started driving, so sorry for so may questions!

Comment: Stay put. Do not proceed if you do not feel it is safe or you're not certain it's legal. Let them honk all day or overake you.

Comment: As a general rule, don't let other drivers intimidate you into doing unsafe or illegal things by honking. You're never required to make a right turn on red, even if it annoys the heck out of everyone behind you, though doing so when you can is advisable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: Strange.  When I lived in Boston people didn't stop at red lights.  At all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making right turn on red onto Bacon from Oak is not Legal.

If you look at traffic light installed at Arbor and Bacon facing Oak Street you can see a blurred white sign, which is actually a "No Turn on Red" sign.

So on this intersection you can turn right from Arbor onto Bacon Street and from Bacon onto Arbor Circle.  Other right on Red are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Is it usual for these signs to be placed in such hard-to-see spots? Usually, I've always seen "No turn on red" signs to be placed in easily identifiable positions, such as hanged up high just below the light, in clear view.

Comment: @Manish In areas of older construction yes this is fairly normal.  But you should be able to see it at the intersection.

Comment: @Manish When you reach the stop line, it will be visible. There is a duplicate sign on the far side traffic light pole. But I can tell that most of these signs are several decades old.  So are the traffic lights themselves. The cyclist sign is relatively new, though.

Comment: It's worth noting that even where, as here, a right turn on red is _permitted_, it is never _required_; the driver is perfectly entitled to wait until the light turns green if they feel it would be safer, are unsure of the laws, or otherwise prefer to do so.

Comment: @mlc True.  But it is annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Karlson called it. Here's the pic. You need to proceed a bit further forward in google streetview. The no turn on red sign is actually hidden behind the three yellow signs and the stop here to turn left white sign:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't see that one.  Saw the one across the street.

Comment: It's on the right hand side. I think only the foremost car would ever be able to see it.

Comment: I hate those kinds of intersection.

Comment: This particular "No Turn on Red" sign is present in the 2013 and 2015 Google Street View, but not in the 2019 one, in which the post and light are present, but this sign is no longer on the post.

Comment: @shoover In the 2022 street view it's been moved across the intersection to be located under the traffic signal.